# Python/Django - Input radiobutton to autosend email

Tags: python, jquery, django, sqlite, django-views

I'm trying to set up a radiobutton input that let's you choose to send email automatically. What I want is a form that gives input: `manual` or `auto`. This will the one row I have in the sqlite3 database for this:

```
class AutoSendMail(models.Model):
    auto = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manual = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So eventually what I want is that in `AutoSendMail` the `auto` is set to `true` when the checkbox is checked + `manual` to `true` (or vise versa when the checkbox is unchecked, depending on the checkbox input)

I got as far as this:

**mailindex.html**

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>Send email automatically </label>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="{{auto_send.auto}}">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> <!-- Import Jquery Here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox').change(function() {
        $.post("mailbox/auto_send/", {
            id: 1,
            isauto: this.checked,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**urls.py**

```
  path('mailbox/auto_send/', login_required(views.AutoSendView.as_view()), name='auto_send'),
```

**models.py**

```
class AutoSendMail(models.Model):
    auto = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manual = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class AutoSendView(generic.TemplateView):
    model = AutoSendMail.objects.all()[0]
    extra_context = {"mailbox_page": "active"}
    context_object_name = 'auto_send'
    template_name = 'core/mailbox/mailindex.html'

    def post(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
        w = AutoSendMail.objects.get(id=1)
        logger.info(w.type)

        if self.request.POST['isauto'] == 'true':
            logger.info("check isauto True")
            logger.info(w.type)
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(auto=True)
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(manual=False)

        elif self.request.POST['isauto'] == 'false':
            logger.info("check isauto False")
            logger.info(w.type)
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(auto=False)
            AutoSendMail.objects.filter(pk=1).update(manual=True)
        else:
            logger.info("check not recognized")
```

EDIT:

When I tick the box I do get a signal from `checkbox` > `urls.py` > `views.py`. But in what I do it only gives vale `true` to `views.py`. How do I make the unchecked checkbox give `false` and the checked checkbox to `true`
Hope someone can help me :)